# Improving Customer First Fulfillment Rate

Tags: inventory, supply-chain

Data Available:

- Historical Weekly Demand
- Total SKU's = ~ 2500
- Historical Lead times (Most Suppliers' Shipping from Asia to the US)

Problem to solve:

- Improve First Fulfillment Rate to the Customer from a distribution center in the US

Questions (I will keep updating as I am working on this project):

- Should I assume my demand and lead times to follow a normal distribution, if not what are some of the suggestions on testing my data w.r.t other distributions? Should I use weekly demand, monthly demand etc. to test? Same question for the lead times.

Comment: Why do you assume that the demand and lead time have to follow normal distribution? Do you have any representation about that?

Answer (score 3):

Before asking if demand and lead time have a specific distribution (normal or other), you might want to ask whether they have stationary distributions or exhibit trend and/or seasonality. If the distributions are not stationary, you need to fit a time series model to them, then ask about the distribution of the residuals. In determining the best model, I think you will want to use [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

Once you are at the point of worrying about normal versus other distributions, and assuming you have enough data (the definition of "enough" being rather fuzzy), I would suggest plotting the data (actual demand/LT if stationary, residuals from the time series model if not) and looking at whether the plot looks reasonably symmetric. If not, look for a distribution that has a similar shape. I would again suggest using cross-validation to pick the right distribution(s).

As far as daily v. weekly v. monthly data, I would use whatever granularity the sample has (i.e., I would not aggregate) when testing for stationarity. If the data proves to be stationary, then it might make sense to aggregate depending on what the ultimate goal of your model is. If you are trying to determine monthly order sizes, aggregating to monthly data is reasonable. If you are determining weekly order sizes, aggregating to monthly does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about using the Normal distribution. It allows for negative values.  Lead times are never < 0. Demand is almost never < 0 ( only if product returns > product sales). An obvious alternative distribution that does not allow negative values is the Poisson. If demands arrive in batches, the Compound Poisson might be useful (see Wikipedia).
If you use monthly data, the Normal assumption is safer, i.e., less likely to result in negative values when you fit a Normal distribution to the data.
Do you have demand data or just sales data? Sales underestimates true demand when you have stockouts.